# My jquery window scroll stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm seriously about to karate chop my computer.

I got this code and it works in firefox but not chrome:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    if ($('html, body').scrollTop() > 25) {
        console.log("scrolled");
        //do stuff
    }
    else {
        //do other stuff
    }
});
```

It's not loggin scrolled in the chrome dev tools console.

Anyone know whats up.

cheers.

Comment: Have you tried using `$(document)` instead of `$('html, body')`?

Comment: Try this one 
`$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
          // something here
        } else {
          // something here
        }
      });`

Comment: Does the scroll event still fire?? If not, try binding the scroll event to `$(document)`. But if the event works.. then most probably what @JiFus commented above would work

Comment: @JiFus Cheers for that don't know how I missed that, I guess it is late friday afternoon. Time for a break :)

Comment: @WebDevGuy You can use $(window).on("scroll", function() {}) and $(this).scrollTop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `document` instead of `window` in your JavaScript.

```js
$( document ).scroll( function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
        console.log("scrolled");
        //do stuff
    }
    else {
        //do other stuff
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(window).on("scroll", function() {})` and `$(this).scrollTop()` like following.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        console.log("more than 200");
        //do stuff
    }
    else {
        console.log("less than 200")
    }
});
```

```css
div#yourdiv {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yourdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

update you jquery version, avoid doing anything on scroll for maximum responsiveness